# How to check the Bluemix activity status?

Tags: ibm-cloud, status

This afternoon of Oct 19th we have scheduled here in Paris an user interaction by using a Bluemix application. Is there any way to check if either the Bluemix platform is going to be up and running, or it is going to be stopped for maintenance? Moreover, is it there any process in place to check it? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can check status and scheduled maintenance for Bluemix in the following link:

http://ibm.biz/bluemixstatus

On that same site you can also subscribe to an RSS feed to have status updates and information about maintenance show up in your reader.